# Can I set default max length for string fields in struct?

Tags: validation, go, struct, reflection, max-size

I have multiple structs in my application using golang. Some fields in a struct have *maxsize* tags, some does not have.
for e.g:

```
type structone struct {
  fieldone string `valid:MaxSize(2)`
  fieldtwo string 
}

type structtwo struct {
  fieldone string `valid:MaxSize(2)`
  fieldtwo string 
}
```

So I want to set default maxsize for all fields, if does not contain any valid max size tags in run time. Is it possible? Can somebody help.

Answer (score 4):

> Can I set default max length for string fields in struct?

No.

Answer (score 2):

The `string` predeclared type does not allow you to limit the length of the `string` value it may hold.

What you may do is use an unexported field so it cannot be accessed (set) outside of your package, and provide a setter method in which you check the length, and refuse to set it if it does not meet your requirements (or cap the value to the allowed max).

For example:

```
func (s *structone) SetFieldone(v string) error {
    if len(v) > 2 {
        return errors.New("too long")
    }
    s.fieldone = v
    return nil
}
```

Comment: The problem is I have hundreds of struct like this in my application and I will have to define for each of them. :(

Comment: he is looking to statically load his program, programmatically add tag, then save the updated to program. ast etc..

Answer (score 0):

The other answers seem to assume you are using vanilla strings in Go and asking if you could limit their max size. That could be achieved with some of the suggestions made.

However, from the code snippet you have provided, I infer that you are asking whether the [validate go package](https://godoc.org/github.com/astaxie/beego/validation) can specify a default max size of all fields in a struct using tags.

Unfortunately, that library does not currently support specifying a default validation tag for all fields. You have to explicitly define the validation tag for all fields of a struct.

What you are trying to achieve is possible, however, but the library needs to be extended.

One suggestion is extending it to support syntax such as:

```
type MyStruct struct {
    valid.Default `valid:MaxSize(5)`

    field1 string
    field2 string
}
```

Comment: Yes you are right and I am not depending on library. I wanted to achieve it using my own code during runtime and then provide that struct to library so it can validate properly.

Comment: I like your suggestion. could you provide an example for this?

Comment: I will attempt to write some code to achieve that. Best case scenario, I will come up with a fork for the library that supports what you need. I will set aside some time to tinker with this today.

Answer (score 0):

this program read itself, add the tag `valid:MaxSize(2)` to the property `structone.fieldone`, then prints the updated program to `os.Stdout`.

```
package main

import (
    "go/ast"
    "go/printer"
    "go/token"
    "log"
    "os"
    "strings"

    "golang.org/x/tools/go/ast/astutil"
    "golang.org/x/tools/go/loader"
)

type structone struct {
    fieldone string
    fieldtwo string
}

func main() {
    var conf loader.Config
    _, err := conf.FromArgs([]string{"."}, false)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    prog, err := conf.Load()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    astutil.Apply(prog.InitialPackages()[0].Files[0], addTag("structone.fieldone", "`valid:MaxSize(2)`"), nil)

    printer.Fprint(os.Stdout, prog.Fset, prog.InitialPackages()[0].Files[0])
}

func addTag(p string, tag string) func(*astutil.Cursor) bool {
    pp := strings.Split(p, ".")
    sName := pp[0]
    pName := pp[1]
    return func(cursor *astutil.Cursor) bool {
        n := cursor.Node()
        if x, ok := n.(*ast.TypeSpec); ok {
            return x.Name.Name == sName
        } else if x, ok := n.(*ast.Field); ok {
            for _, v := range x.Names {
                if v.Name == pName {
                    x.Tag = &ast.BasicLit{
                        Value: tag,
                        Kind:  token.STRING,
                    }
                }
            }
        } else if _, ok := n.(*ast.File); ok {
            return true
        } else if _, ok := n.(*ast.GenDecl); ok {
            return true
        } else if _, ok := n.(*ast.TypeSpec); ok {
            return true
        } else if _, ok := n.(*ast.StructType); ok {
            return true
        } else if _, ok := n.(*ast.FieldList); ok {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}
```